# Lambda service throws error execution role does not have permissions to call receiveMessage on SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue and I want to trigger a lambda function when a message arrives in the queue.  I have written the lambda function and that works successfully when I click the "Test" button.  When I go to SQS and try to configure it as a lambda trigger I see the error message below.

I have created the SQS queue and lambda function using the same user and role and the lambda function has execute permissions against the same role.

I also have also added SQS receiveMessage permission but it doesn't seem to make a difference unless I'm doing something wrong when I set it.

What could be causing the problem?

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: You need to check permission in the SQS itself as well.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- Hi as far as i can understand your lambda needs the following permission on it [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)
- Hope its not in a VPC.

[image: aws_lambda_permission]

- Or may be give it a god mode on `sqs:*` just for testing it.
- If that works maybe later on you can then go for specific methods only. Attached a policy for a lambda role you might have to change account_number to your account no if you need to invoke another lambda form this lambda

  ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:account_number:function:*"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "logs:PutLogEvents",
                   "logs:CreateLogStream",
                   "logs:CreateLogGroup"
               ],
               "Resource": "*"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "sqs:*"
               ],
               "Resource": "*"
           }
       ]
   }
  ```

Answer (score 22):

Although solution for this may have been achieved by now.. but since this thread was suggested to me at the top.. i will post the answer for other users:

I faced same issue even after giving SQS full access to user. The problem is with the lambda execution role. When lambda is created, it needs to be assigned a lambda execution role. Most users assign the auto-generated execution role while creating lambda. That execution role does not have permissions for SQS.

So open lambda >> Click Permissions tab >> edit execution role at the top >> assign SQS permissions >> boom.

[edit]This is now under Configuration >> Permissions

[image: permissions tab showing execution role]

Comment: works like a charm thanks a million bro

Answer (score 19):

You need following permissions attached to the role, your lambda assumes

- sqs:ReceiveMessage
- sqs:DeleteMessage
- sqs:GetQueueAttributes

In case you are using Terraform:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "YOUR_DOCUMENT" {
  statement {
    sid       = "some_id"
    actions   = [
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:DeleteMessage",
      "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_sqs_queue.YOUR_QUEUE.arn
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "YOUR_POLICY" {
  name   = "your_policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.YOUR_DOCUMENT.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "POLICY_ATTACHMENT" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.YOUR_LAMBDA_ROLE.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.YOUR_POLICY.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "YOUR_LAMBDA" {
  ....
  role = aws_iam_role.YOUR_LAMBDA_ROLE.arn
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar issue when trying to add an SQS trigger to my Lambda function.

> An error occurred when creating the trigger: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS

The way I solved it was to simply add permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS in the execution role of the Lambda function.

**To do this simply**:

- Go to **IAM** in the AWS Console
- Click on roles
- Select your Lambda function execution role or create one if you don't already have
- Add the AWS managed LambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole policy to the role. The policy contains all the permissions to call the required actions on SQS from Lambda. The ARN of the policy is `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole`.
- Save the role, and then try again to add the trigger. This time it will work fine.